# Does UNO and Nano have the same pins?

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-nano

Do Arduino Nano Atmega328p have the same pins as Arduino/Gizduino Uno Atmega328p?

Comment: uno and nano are about the two closest together AVR boards; nano is a small uno.

Answer (score 1):

The '328P uC on the boards is the same die. The 328P in DIP has 4 fewer pins brought out (Vcc, Gnd, A6, A7) compared to the surface mount parts. The boards themselves then bring the pins out to edge connectors in physically different locations.

Comment: Gizmoduino Uno has SMD ATmega328 with A6 and A7 brought out